# From a generic manager class, how to access in a static way information about it's instances?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, static

I am trying to create a online arena game where players can create custom arenas to play on. I wish to save the arena settings in a MySQL database so that it saves the arena for further playing.

The catch is, there are different variations of Arenas. So there can be jungle arenas, desert ones, etc. All of these different variations (subclasses of the abstract class Arena) must be stored in different tables since the variables (and thus the columns) are different for each type of arenas.

My question is : from the Manager class described below containing an array of a generic type, how can I get the required columns from the child (T) class and it's parent. I am using a generic type because I also want to use this class for managing player's informations (which also need to be stored in a database) later.

Here is the Manager class:

```
public class Manager<T extends Savable> {
  private Connection connection;
  private List<Column<?>> columns;

  private List<T> instances;

  public Manager() {
    fillColumnArray()

    try {
      connection = getSQLConnection();
      Statement s = connection.createStatement();
      s.executeUpdate(getCreateQuery())
      s.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void fillColumnArray() {
    // Somehow, manages to get the needed columns from
    // the parent class and the child class
  }

  public Connection getSQLConnection() {
    // Creates a mysql connection to a database
    // from parameters on a local file and returns it
  }

  public String getCreateQuery() {
    // Creates the query from the previously found columns
  }

  /* */
}
```

Here is the Column class used in the Manager:

```
public class Column<U> {
  private String name;
  private U defaultValue;

  /* */
}
```

And here are possible variables for the Arena class and one possible children

```
public abstract class Arena implements Savable {
  private Vector centerPosition;
  private int radius;
  private int gameLenght;

  /* */
}

public class JungleArena extends Arena {
  private int treeHeight;
  private boolean daytime;

  /* */
}
```

I thought of many different possibilities. One of them was to add a requestColumns() method in the Savable interface but this option doesn't work because upon creation of the Manager, I can only access the T class in a static way.

So then I thought of adding a static method requestColumns() inside both the child and the parent but since I am using a generic type, the compiler would not understand where the method comes from.

Then I thought of casting the T type to it's specefic Arena type but then it would not work further in my project when using the same class for storing players.

Hope this is clear enough.

Is anyone having an idea to make things work or just another way of doing things from your understanding?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, you're wondering how to tell the manager what table to save the values to according to the `Arena`'s class?

Comment: Well, I want to tell the manager what values will be in the table

Comment: Can you use the "instanceof" operator to check what the class is?

Comment: I don't know yet what are going to be the child classes, this is just a package for me to use.

Comment: I can see a few issues with your approach (I ran into a similar problem myself recently): (1) every time your manager encounters a new class, it will need to create a new table for that class. (2) And for that, it will need to keep track of every class it has ever encountered, or poll the database for every table with a name corresponding to the class it encountered every time it is fed a class. (3) If you want to list all of the fields to be stored from a class, either your manager will have to use `Reflection` to get the field names, or your class will have to carry a list of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to do this statically considering you have the instance already and you can use the instance to get this information for you in a generic way. I'm also not clear how you intend to get the values for the columns from the class, this answer handles that if you haven't yet.

Personally, absent any worthy framework capable of this already, I'd define an annotation to put on the public getters of the column fields. Like so:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Column {
    String name() default "";
}
```

You could then use reflection to get those getters and then invoke the methods on the instance thereby getting the values as well. For example, given this class:

```
class Entity {
    ...

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public getName() { return name; }

    @Column(name = "Height")
    public getHeight() { return height; }
}
```

I could get the column names and values like so:

```
    Entity e = new Entity("First", 42);
    Method[] methods = e.getClass().getMethods();
    Map<String, Method> colums = new HashMap<>();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        Column c = m.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (c != null) {
            colums.put(c.name(), m);
        }
    }
    colums.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().invoke(e));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


Output >
Height: 42
Name: First
```